# Forcing decision trees into minimum degrees

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, decision-tree, party

Can a decision tree be forced into a specific degree even if previously discarded?

I tried to build a decision tree with **Party Package (ctree)** but it is ignored from the parameters/categories that are set up. 
Is there a way to include a decision tree with all of the set categories (even the results are close)? 
I want to force the tree to **minimum number of nodes**.

For example, in the attched plot, there is 7 nodes. 
I want to force the tree to be with 10 nodes.
This is possible?

Thanks!

[image: Optimum tree for iris]

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Add reproducible code and describe your issue. Here is an example how you can parameterize number of nodes/trees if needed:

```
library(caret)
modFit<-train(classifier~., data=training, method="rf", ntree=100, importance=TRUE, maxnodes=3)
```

More details about tree-based models (with package 'caret'):

```
http://topepo.github.io/caret/Tree_Based_Model.html
```

Comment: Not sure what is the goal of this exercise. But you can get different number of nodes by basically changing the training parameters. E.g. next values will give you desired 10 nodes:
`tree1 <- tree(Species~Sepal.Width+Petal.Width, control = tree.control(nobs=150,mincut=3, minsize=7, mindev=0), data=iris)`

Comment: I don't think that forcing a tree to have exactly 10 nodes is easily possible in `ctree()` (or `rpart()` either). You have various tuning options such as the minimal node size, the maximal depth of the tree, and for `ctree()` the significance level required to keep on splitting. Modifying these, as previously mentioned by @Alex, will can lead to a tree of (about) the desired size.